# Azure Docker Container Service Multiple Instances

Tags: azure, docker

I'm using Azure for the first time to deploy a web app. More specifically, I'm using the Docker Container Service to do this. I already have one instance of it deployed. But, I want to also deploy 2 more instances of the same web app. I want each instance to have a different URL. What is the best way of doing this? Do I have to add a new container service for each new instance and repeat the steps I did for deploying the first instance?

Answer (score 0):

As in case of Azure Container Service (ACS),

You choose a container orchestrator i.e. Swarm, DC\OS and Kubernetes (Because creating replicas works differently in each of them).

In case of Swarm then either create a separate application container for the same application *with a different end point* and use automatic discovery feature for different URL(s) or choose a reverse-proxy load-balancer such as Nginx which will work on the same URL but on a different port (My blog [here](http://kjanshair.azurewebsites.net/docker/dockercompose) might help you).

Creating replicas across a cluster are used for **Load Balancing**, **Routing Mesh**, **Scaling** and **Rolling updates** etc.